# How can I select data from my database in time intervals?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have the following table in a database:

```
ID  | Date            | Data |
------------------------------
0   |2020-01-01 08:00 | 123
1   |2020-01-01 08:01 | 456
2   |2020-01-01 08:02 | 789
3   |2020-01-01 08:03 | 222
4   |2020-01-01 08:04 | 323
5   |2020-01-01 08:05 | 565
6   |2020-01-01 08:06 | 097
7   |2020-01-01 08:07 | 112
8   |2020-01-01 08:08 | 652
9   |2020-01-01 08:09 | 547
10  |2020-01-01 08:10 | 187
```

Is there a way to use a select statement to grab the data in intervals? For example, selecting data in 2 minutes intervals so that records `0,2,4,6,8, and 10` would show? Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE (Date is 2 minute intervals)
ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`DATEPART()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and [modulo (`%`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_name
WHERE DATEPART(mi, [Date]) % 2 = 0
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7e6af0/4)

Comment: Great answer, thank you for your quick response. If I needed to do this for hours and seconds, would that be possible as well? Is it just as simple and using `ho` and `se` for hours and seconds?

Comment: @GreenSaber - Yes. Please follow the link I provided and pickup ***correct*** abbreviation for hours and seconds.